# How to get Image data from one class to another

Tags: react-native, imagepicker

I am using imagePicker in a gifted chat. I want to display captured image from camera to another class. I want to access the **source** to another class here is the code

```
    renderCameraImage = () => (
        <Image
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={{ uri: this.state.filePath.uri }}
        />
    )
```

if i use

```
source={{ uri: this.props.filePath.uri }}
```

this would not work for sure. How can i access the source ?

Comment: What you mean by ```this would not work```? at least share your error then someone might be able to help you.

Comment: undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.filepath.uri)

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing ```filePath``` as props?

Comment: I just want to use source as a props

Comment: what you mean by ```source as a props```?